# How do I prevent Gridview from exporting data to Excel with hyperlinks on the column headers?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

Good day,

I have browsed the net for solution but found none.

We wrote a code that displays results on Gridview with a button to export data to an excel spreadsheet.

The Gridview has paging and sorting enabled.

However, the issue is that the exported data appears to have hyperlinks on the column headers.

When  you click on any of the column headers, the following error occurs:

*Microsoft Office has identified potential security concern.
To protect your computer, click only those links from trusted sources...*

Is there a way to export data to Excel from Gridview without hyperlinks on the column headers?

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/drafts/98280) for example. All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ExportToExcel function probably does a RenderControl to an HtmlTextWriter.  Before calling that function, you can turn sorting off on the GridView.  You also have to be sure to call DataBind on the GridView right after that though.  The sequence should be:

```
' turn sorting off and call DataBind()
gvMyGridView.AllowSorting = False
gvMyGridView.DataBind()

' call your ExportToExcel function
ExportToExcel(gvMyGridView, "MyExport")

' turn sorting back on
gvMyGridView.AllowSorting = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `gridview` to generate the excel file you should use the `Dataset` or `Datatable` you used to populate the `gridview`.

The code to do so would be.

```
public void ExportDataTableToExcel(DataTable dt, string filename)
    {
        HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        // first let's clean up the response.object   
        response.Clear();
        response.Charset = "";

        // set the response mime type for excel   
        response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");

        // create a string writer   
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                // instantiate a datagrid   
                DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
                dg.DataSource = dt;

                dg.DataBind();
                dg.RenderControl(htw);
                response.Write(sw.ToString());
                response.End();
            }
        }

    }
```

All you have to do is create a class with the above function and in the code of your page make it's object and call this function with the datatable and the name of the file.